# Delphi Indy TCP Client/Server communication best approach

Tags: sockets, delphi, tcp, communication, indy

I have a client and a server application that is communicating just fine, there is a TIdCmdTCPServer in the server and a TIdTCPClient in the client.

The client has to authenticate in the server, the client asks the server for the newest version information and downloads any updates, and other communications. All this communication with TIdTCPClient.SendCmd() and TIdTCPClient.LastCmdResult.Text.Text.

The way it is, the server receives commands and replies, the clients only receives replies, never commands, and I would like to implement a way to make the client receives commands. But as I heard, if the client uses SendCmd it should never be listening for data like ReadLn() as it would interfere with the reply expected in SendCmd.
  I thought of making a command to check for commands, for example, the client would send a command like "IsThereCommandForMe" and the server would have a pool of commands to each client and when the client asks, the server send it in the reply, but I think it would not be a good approach as there would be a big delay between the commands being available and the client asking for it. I also thought of making a new connection with new components, for example a TIdCmdTcpClient, but then there would be 2 connections for each client, I don't like that idea as I think it could easily give problems in the communication.

The reason I want this, is that I want to implement a chat functionality in the client, and it should be receiving messages from the server without asking for it all the time, imagine all clients continually asking the server if there is message for them. And I would like to be able to inform the client when there is an update available instead the client being asking if there is any. And with this I could send more commands to the client too.

what are your thoughts about this ? how can I make the server receiving commands from the clients, but also sends them ?

Comment: In one of my projects I used the approach of having both TIdTCPClient and TIdRCPServer components both on server and client side. I went for this approach as I needed two way communication as you do. And this came verry usefull later on when I needed to send large amount of information from one client to another. Without such approach I would be forced to route all that data through server which would cause heavy load on it. But with this approach I already have needed "infrastructure" to implement Peer-To-Peer comunication.

Comment: So now client that requires that information from another client sends special message to the server. Server then sends the IP information of that other client back to the requesting client and notifies that other client that requesting client will try to establish a direct connection. This last part is intended as aditional security check to prefent someone else to infiltrate into the system posing as another client.

Comment: @SilverWarior admins do not show much love for applications which open (server) ports on client PCs :)

Comment: @mjn Yes I know that. I have written comments about such solution only becouse OP was already considering it in order to provide some more infomration on such idea (what it could be established by it). It is now up to OP wheter he uses it or not. But your solution that you are suggesting in your answer is better. So if I would be making that project of mine now I would rather go with your solution.

Comment: @SilverWarior, I prefer to not use both connections on each client with the server, it doesn't seem right to have 2 connections for the same client, but latter I might want to implement some file transfer protocol between clients and as you said this data could cause a load in the server, maybe this connection between two clients app could be created just for a file transfer ans then closed again. but this is of second importance for now. but tanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

TCP sockets are bidirectional by design. Once the connection between 'client' and 'server' has been established, they are symmetric and data can be sent at any time from any side over the same socket.

It only depends on the protocol (which is just written 'contract' for the communication) which communication model is used. HTTP for example uses a request/reply model. With Telnet for example, both sides can initate data transmissions. (If you take a look at the Indy implementation for Telnet, you will see that it uses a background thread to listen for server data, but it uses the same socket connection in the main thread to send data from client to server).

A "full duplex" protocol which supports both request/response and server push, and also is firewall-friendly, is [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). With WebSockets (a HTTP upgrade), the server can send data to the connected client(s) any time. This would meet your 'chat' requirement.

If you use TIdTCPClient / TIdCmdTCPServer, corporate firewalls might block the communication.

Comment: Thanks @mjn your answer is very helpful, I am doing some research about TIdTelnetServer and TIdTelnet.
the Ideia about WebSockets seems better, but it seems there is no free and powerful components for delphi like INDY.
I am going to post again after some research. and tanks again for your effort on helping.

Comment: @CarlosGoncalves maybe this is helpful (based on Indy) https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/websocket-client-and-server-library-for-delphi/

Comment: Thanks @mjn
I found another websocket at http://websockets.esegece.com/
But while trying it out, I fell it is not the best approach for my application, As it does not need browser integration or have firewall problems.

I am thinking about developing my own Tcp protocol with indy.
If I don't use the default indy Commands components, I can build a protocol that could send messages both ways and even wait for replays if the read is done for only one place with a different thread exclusive for that.